# How to make Entity Framework load related entities after resetting the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have a little problem with Entity Framework. I have three basic entities that are related to other entities (through virtual properties).

When I open my program for the first time it all goes well. I can do everything I want and the entities are related the way they have to be. When I close the program and open it again, I automatically get a NullReferenceException from one of the entities, establishing that the related entity it is trying to access is null.

I am trying to use Lazy Loading, hence why every related Entity is virtual, and every Entity knows its ID and the related entity's ID as well.

Do someone know why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Are you sure that your **entity has stored in database** (see your tables using sql server) ? Is your database is **attached to sql server** or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your entity has stored in database and your are attached to sql server

When you want read entity you must include other entities that you want

Add `System.Data.Entity` reference to your c# file

```
using ( context db = new Context())
{
    List<Customer> lc = ( from c in db.Customers.Include(c=> c.Orders) select c).ToList();
}
```